# React form onSubmit and onClick do not fire when inside Zurb Foundation "Reveal" dialog

Tags: javascript, reactjs, zurb-foundation, onsubmit

I have the following code, which worked perfectly prior to upgrading from React 16.12.0 to React 17.0.0, but now my events no longer fire (i.e. the `console.log` statement is never printed).

```js
class MyClass extends PureComponent {
    handleSubmit = () => {
        console.log('Submitted!');
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div className='reveal' id='dialog'>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I've tried changing my code to the following instead, but this event does not fire either.

```js
class MyClass extends PureComponent {
    handleSubmit = () => {
        console.log('Submitted!');
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div className='reveal' id='dialog'>
                <form>
                    <button onClick={this.handleSubmit} type='submit'>Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I know this has something to do with the fact that the form is inside a Zurb Foundation "Reveal" dialog, but I have no idea why this problem only occurs when upgrading to React 17.

Comment: Try moving the submit handler to the form instead of the button. `type="submit"` is the default for `button` btw.

Comment: @LyndenNoye, as my question indicates, I've tried it both ways.

Answer (score 1):

I'm unable to reproduce this – works just fine in this minimal example derived from your code.

```js
class MyClass extends React.PureComponent {
    handleSubmit = () => {
        alert('Submitted!');
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
            </form>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyClass />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

Comment: Turns out my problem may not have to do with React, but with Zurb Foundation. My form is inside a "reveal" dialog, which seems to be high jacking all events, and I have no idea how to fix this.